# Can you make a reliable random-number generator from the stock market?

Tags: random

Can the stock market be used to make a reliable random number generator?

I'm not necessarily asking if it follows a random walk which was discussed more [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-random-are-financial-data-series), nor am I asking if everything about it is 100% random.

I'm just wondering if there is data that can be extracted out in such a way that a reliable random number generator can be created.

Comment: Depends on how you define "the stock market" and "reliable random number" and that is just for starters.

Comment: Well, stock market being any data you can get from the stock graphs. reliable meaning, well, aren't there tests that determine if a random number generator is reliable or not?

Comment: I would guess looking at whether the last digit of, say, aapl closing price rounds to a $.05$ or a $.00$ would be a pretty decent independent bernoulli variable. Of course this guess could be wildly wrong

Comment: Oh, that's a good thought @spaceisdarkgreen. I guess things like that can be used. I guess that kind of leads into pseudo-random number generator territory where anything can be used as a seed to make a string of pretty much random numbers also. Thanks for the thoughts guys :)